# Wordpress Tags already entered in Post creation and not displaying in Tags section

Tags: wordpress, tags

Tags were entered in the Post creation:

[image]

Tags aren`t showing in the Tags section

[image]

Due to this I can`t display a tag cloud...

I have a very large list of already entered tags by post creation,

How can I export the tags of each posts and import them to the tag section?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: what version of wordpress you using ?

Comment: Using Version 5.0.3

Comment: Let me check and reply soon

Comment: what are the plugin you have installed on website ?

Comment: Contact Form 7,
Duplicate Post,
Force Regenerate Thumbnails,
Insert PHP Code Snippet,
Invisible reCaptcha,
PHP Code For Posts,
Polylang,
Slider Revolution,
Sydney Toolbox,
User Role Editor,
Wordfence Security,
WPBakery Page Builder

Comment: I have checked with default theme and latest wordpress there is no issue found

Comment: I am Using BeTheme

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the guttenberg editor fixed it.